# How do I match name, name here in Regex?

Tags: regex, whitespace, regex-lookarounds

I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work, and after hours of trying, I've got to ask for help.

This is the string I'm scanning.

```
F:\Downloads\Downloads\500 Comics CCC English\Jack, Byrd - Art #01.cbr
```

This is the current Regex I'm using to try to match what I want.

```
(?i)English\\(?<Writer>.*(?= ))(?-i)
```

It matches English\Jack, Byrd - Art

All I want it to match is Jack, Byrd (with no space after it.)

For some reason, the only space I can get it to match is the space after Art.
No matter what I try, it will only match that space.  It's like it doesn't consider the other spaces to be spaces.

Comment: `.*\\(.+, [^ ]+)`?

Comment: Thank you!!  I modified it to (?i)English\\(.+, [^ ]+)(?-i) and it worked.  Now I just have to figure out what you wrote, and where to put <Writer>.

Comment: Can someone explain `<Writer>` to me?  Is that a way of naming a capture group or an error or...?

Comment: It's how you put in a group name.  At least it works in the program I'm using.

Comment: This is the final string that worked for me.  (?i)English\\(?<Writer>.+, [^ ]+)(?-i).  <Writer> would be the same as $1 or $2, etc. group name.  Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(?i)English\\(?<Writer>.*(?= ))(?-i)` pattern contains `.*` that grabs as many chars as it can and then backtracking results in the `English\Jack, Byrd - Art` match because the space after `Art` is the last space (the space is required due to the positive lookahead `(?= )`).

There are several ways to fix it depending on the contexts you have. If there is always a space-hyphen-space after the necessary value add a space and hyphen to the lookahead

```
(?i)English\\(?<Writer>.*(?= - ))(?-i)
```

If the value is always a string of non-whitespace chars, comma, space and again a string of non-whitespace chars use

```
(?i)English\\(?<Writer>\S+,\s*\S+)(?-i)
```

where `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars.

For those who wonder what a `(?<Write>...)` is, the construct is called a  *named capturing group* and is referenced to as `\k<Writer>` when used inside the same regex pattern or as `${Writer}` when used inside a string replacement argument.